# Sub-processing pipe write to file malfunction

Tags: python, shell, unix, subprocess, pipe

Executing this in shell gets me tangible results:

```
wget -O c1 --no-cache "http://some.website" | sed "1,259d" c1 | sed "4,2002d"
```

Doing this in Python gets me nothing:

```
subprocess.call(shlex.split("wget -O c1 --no-cache \"http://some.website/tofile\""))
c1 = open("c1",'w')
first = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("sed \"1,259d\" c1"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("sed \"4,2002d\""), stdin=first.stdout, stdout=c1)
c1.close()
```

Doing this also gets me no results:

```
c1.write(subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("sed \"4,2002d\""), stdin=first.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0])
```

By 'gets me nothing' I mean blank output in the file. Does anyone see anything out of the ordinary here?

Comment: Have you tried this in the Python command-line interpreter? What do the various variables show at each step along the way?

Comment: They are subprocess.Popen objects. `c1` of course, is just a file object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `c1 = open("c1",'w')` opens file `c1` for writing and truncates any existing data, so everything wget wrote to the file gets erased before you call sed.

Anyway, I think `shlex.split` is generally awkward. I prefer to build the args list manually:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

p0 = Popen(['wget', '-O', '-', 'http://www.google.com'], stdout=PIPE)
p1 = Popen(['sed', '2,8d'], stdin=p0.stdout, stdout=PIPE) 
with open('c1', 'w') as c1:
    p2 = Popen(['sed', '2,7d'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=c1)
    p2.wait()
```

However, there's no obvious reason a Python programmer should have to call out to sed. Python has string methods and regular expressions. Also, instead of wget you can use `urllib2.urlopen`.

Comment: Minor correction, put p0 outside of `with` and put p0.wait() after it, run p1 without piping to p0, and everything is okay with it. Yea, I realized that urllib could get the job done, I just wanted to know why this wasn't working. Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: @eazar001: p1 is getting its data piped from p0. I tested, and it works on my end. I did forget to `wait`, however.

Comment: my workaround was just to open up a `cc1` and output to that. Then run a process to simply `mv cc1 c1`. A little dirty, but it worked. Meh, about the wait. It happens, I guess it takes a while for the wget to do its job.

Answer (score 3):

I always use [plumbum](http://plumbum.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for running external commands. It provides a very intuitive interface and, of course, takes care of escaping for me.

Would look something like:

```
from plumbum.cmd import wget, sed
cmd1 = wget['-O', 'c1']['--no-cache']["http://some.website"]
cmd2 = sed["1,259d"]['c1'] | sed["4,2002d"]
print cmd1
cmd1()  # run it
print cmd2
cmd2()  # run it
```

Comment: This definitely does seems like a useful tool, I'll have to try it out some time.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do everything all in pipes and send the output to a file?

```
wget -O - "http://www.google.com" | sed "1,259d" | sed "4,2002d" > c1
```

Or if you don't want to send it to a file, and want it on stdout instead:

```
wget -O - "http://www.google.com" | sed "1,259d" | sed "4,2002d"
```

And if you want to do it in Python:

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("wget -O - \"http://www.google.com\" | sed \"1,259d\" | sed \"4,2002d\""), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
result = pipe.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: Was able to use a variation of your suggestion, and it worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of making life easier for people who more-or-less may be running into the same type of problem, I have decided to post the final revised code, which factored in comments about `c1` and overwriting of data. Of particular interest is the usage of `communicate()` which helped to completely eliminate any manifestations of zombie processes, which were quite irritating. Also, I found it useful to use `subprocess.call` in portions where piping wasn't necessary. No `wait()` was necessary in the end. Ultimately, staying away from `sed` and `wget` is a good idea, especially with Python's inbuilt tools and `urllib2`.

```
p0 = subprocess.call(shlex.split("wget -Oc1 --no-cache \"http://Some.website/tofile\""))
p1 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("sed \"1,261d\" c1"), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

with open("cc1", 'w') as cc1:
    p2 = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split("sed \"3,2002d\""), stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=cc1)
    p2.communicate()
    p1.communicate()
    p3 = subprocess.call(shlex.split("mv cc1 c1"))
```